# CircularFifoQueue doesn't work inside the method, what to use instead?

Tags: java, queue, fifo, circular-buffer

I need to write the method which let to store  always last 10 (the newset) elements and only 10.I have tried to use CircularFifoBuffer.It works perfectly usee like this:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Queue;
 import org.apache.commons.collections4.queue.CircularFifoQueue;

 public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Queue<Integer> fifo = new CircularFifoQueue<Integer>(3);
    fifo.add(11);
    fifo.add(22);
    fifo.add(33);
    fifo.add(44);
    fifo.add(55);
    System.out.println(fifo); // [33, 44, 55]
```

But it doesn;t work when used inside the method:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.queue.CircularFifoQueue;

public class TV {

   public int channelNumber = 11;

   public int getChannelNumber() {
      return channelNumber;
   }

   public void addToChannelsHistory(int channnelNumber) {
      Queue<Integer> fifo = new CircularFifoQueue<Integer>(3);
      fifo.add(channnelNumber);
      System.out.print(fifo);
   }
}
```

Could you help what to use instead?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the notion of attribute, a member of your class which is a data, not a method:

```
public class TV {

   private final Queue<Integer> fifo = new CircularFifoQueue<Integer>(3);

   public Queue<Integer> getChannelNumbers() {
      return fifo;
   }

   public Integer getChannelNumber() {
      return fifo.isEmpty() ? null : fifo.peek();
   }

   public void addToChannelsHistory(int channnelNumber) {
      fifo.add(channnelNumber);
   }

   public String toString() {
      return fifo.toString();
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      TV tv = new TV();
      tv.addToChannelsHistory(11);
      tv.addToChannelsHistory(22);
      tv.addToChannelsHistory(33);
      tv.addToChannelsHistory(44);
      tv.addToChannelsHistory(55);
      System.out.print( tv );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I've misunderstood, but as far as I can tell by copying this locally, this works. However, in a Java program, the main method is the entry point into the program. If you aren't instantiating your TV class in the main method, the addToChannelHistory method will never get run. For instance, this works for me:

```
public class TV {

    public int channelNumber = 11;

    public int getChannelNumber() {
        return channelNumber;
    }

    public void addToChannelsHistory(int channnelNumber) {

        Queue<Integer> fifo = new CircularFifoQueue<Integer>(3);
        fifo.add(channnelNumber);

        System.out.print(fifo);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TV tv = new TV();
        tv.addToChannelsHistory(11);
        tv.addToChannelsHistory(22);
        tv.addToChannelsHistory(33);
        tv.addToChannelsHistory(44);
        tv.addToChannelsHistory(55);
    }
}
```

Running that program should print out 33 to the console.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have edited your post by error. I don't know how to undo.

Comment: Sorry, my code was not clear. Obviously I am using tv object in main method and I'm calling the method on the object. It doesnt start printing form 33

Comment: Ok I wasn't sure. But the above code is printing 33 for me. Can you show your exact code that you are using? Assuming @Aubin's answer didn't help either?

Comment: public class TV {

 public int channelNumber = 11;

 public int getChannelNumber() {
  return channelNumber;
 }

 public void addToChannelsHistory(int channnelNumber) {

  Queue<Integer> fifo = new CircularFifoQueue<Integer>(3);
  fifo.add(channnelNumber);

  System.out.print(fifo);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  TV tv = new TV();
  tv.addToChannelsHistory(11);
  tv.addToChannelsHistory(22);
  tv.addToChannelsHistory(33);
  tv.addToChannelsHistory(44);
  tv.addToChannelsHistory(55);
 }
}

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to insert the code to look better. Any way it prints [11][22][33][44][55], not from 33.

Comment: ah ok I misunderstood the issue. I thought you were not getting it to print anything. I did not realize it was where the printing was starting. My mistake. Check out @Aubin's answer. That would solve the issue. In your code, you are creating a new Queue each time you run the method, so you are never filling up the size of 3.